# How to find out the amount of SWAP an AWS RDS instance has?

Tags: rds

How to find out the amount of SWAP an AWS RDS instance has?
In EC2 one can SSH and find out the amount of SWAP an instance has but how does one find out is RDS?
The purpose is to configure SWAP usage monitoring for RDS in AWS Cloudwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the RDS database you use.  The bad news is if you're using Aurora with MySQL compatibility it doesn't have a swap metric.  For the other RDS Linux types, you can find `Swap Usage` in the `Monitoring`-> `CloudWatch` section.

[image: RDS Monitoring]

According to the Troubleshooting guide linked below:

> To monitor swap memory, enable Enhanced Monitoring to review metrics in intervals with a granularity of as little as one second. Enhanced Monitoring collects statistics at the host level, and CloudWatch collects data from the hypervisor level every 60 seconds. You can use Enhanced Monitoring to identify increases or decreases that occur for only one second and to see the CPU and memory that are used by individual processes.

**References**

[Aurora Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html)
[RDS Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html)
[Troubleshoot RDS Swap Memory](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-rds-swap-memory/)